# Remove zero dimension in pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, pytorch

I have torch.tensor which has dimension of **0 x 240 x 3 x 540 x 960**

I just want to remove 0 dimension, so I want to have pytorch tensor

size of **240 x 3 x 540 x 960**.

I used `tensor= torch.squeeze(tensor)` to try that, but zero dimension was not removed...

In my case, the size of tensor is variable so I can't hard code it to torch.squeeze..

Is there any simple way to remove undesired dimension in pytorch.tensor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You can't.

The size (=number of elements) in a tensor of shape `0 x 240 x 3 x 540 x 960` is 0.

You can't reshape it to a tensor of shape `240 x 3 x 540 x 960` because that has 373248000 elements.

[`squeeze()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) doc:

> Returns a tensor with all the dimensions of input of size 1 removed.

This removes 1 sized dims, not 0 sized dims, which makes sense.

---

Anyway, the amount of data in your original tensor is 0, which can be presented as any shape with at least one zero dim, but not as shapes whose size > 0.

Comment: Thank you, because squeeze doesn't solve it, Instead, I managed to change the structure of the overall neural network of torch.nn.Module. In my case, the input/output form of the tensor was not correct compared with designed structure of original neural network, and I tried to solve it with a square because zero dimension suddenly occurred, but it didn't work well, and I was able to change the overall layer of the neural network and Finally it worked. Perhaps 0 dimension is an undesired error in the process of making the neural network.